# PowerShell The Try statement is missing its Catch or Finally block

Tags: regex, excel, powershell

I am **very** new to PowerShell and have only recently discovered this gem of a tool. I have pieced together a few different scripts to allow me to search a drive for Excel files and see if they contain a pattern of characters. I think I have everything in it I need, however I keep getting an error with the braces (as far as I can tell).

Does the REGEX portion of my script make sense? Will the two lines below be sufficient in determining whether each cell value matches the prescribed pattern?

```
$formula = $workSheet.cells.item($row,$column).value
if($formula -match [regex]$REGEX)
```

On a separate note, I keep getting an error (see after code for details) when trying to run the script. I have tried adding and removing braces since that is what the message keeps telling me if the problem.

My script is written as such:

```
Function Search-Files-For-Patterns {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param (
        [parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateScript({
            Try {
                If (Test-Path -Path $_) {$True}
                Else {Throw "$($_) is not a valid path!"}
            }
            Catch {
                Throw $_
            }
        })]
        [String]$Source,       
        [parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$SearchText
    )
    $LogCSV = "X:\PowerShell\Scrape.csv"
    $Filelist =  Get-ChildItem $Source -Filter '*.xls*' -Recurse
    $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $DisableAutomationSecurity = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity]::msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
    $EnableAutomationSecurity = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutomationSecurity]::msoAutomationSecurityByUI
    $REGEX = "\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d"

    $Excel.Application.AutomationSecurity = $DisableAutomationSecurity
    Remove-Item $LogCSV -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    Out-File -FilePath $LogCSV -InputObject "File;Count;NAS"
    #"File;Count" > $LogCSV                    
    foreach ($File in $Filelist) {
        $password = ""
        try {
            $Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($File.FullName, 0, 0, 5, $password)
            $Numbers = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
            $NumberCount = 0
            ForEach ($Worksheet in @($Workbook.Sheets)) {
                $rowMax = ($Worksheet.usedRange.rows).count
                $columnMax = ($Worksheet.usedRange.columns).count
                For($row = 1 ; $row -le $rowMax ; $row ++) {
                    For($column = 1 ; $column -le $columnMax ; $column ++) {
                        $formula = $workSheet.cells.item($row,$column).value
                        #[string]$formula = $workSheet.cells.item($row,$column).value
                        if($formula -match [regex]$REGEX) {
                            $Numbers.Add("$($formula.Text);")
                            $NumberCount++
                            if ($NumberCount -eq 25) {break}
                        } #end for if $formula 
                    } #end for $column
                } #end for $row            
                if ($NumberCount -ge 10) {
                    Out-File -FilePath $LogCSV -InputObject "$($File.FullName);$NumberCount;$Numbers" -Append
                } #end if $numbercount >= 10
                $workbook.close($false)
            } #end foreach worksheet
            catch {
                Out-File -FilePath $LogCSV -InputObject "$($File.FullName);File is password protected - skipped;" -Append
            } #end catch
        } #end try <--ERROR OCCURS HERE
    } #end for each file

    $Excel.Application.AutomationSecurity = $EnableAutomationSecurity
    [void][System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$excel)
    [gc]::Collect()
    [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    Remove-Variable excel -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
} #end function
Search-Files-For-Patterns "X:\SomeFolder" "\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d"
```

The error message I'm getting when I try to run this is:

```
At X:\PowerShell\ScrapeG\Search-Files-For-Patterns.ps1:58 char:10
+         } #end try
+          ~
The Try statement is missing its Catch or Finally block.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingCatchOrFinally
```

Any direction / help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You did'nt close the `try` block. Add a `}` after your `} #end foreach worksheet`

Comment: `try {do-stuff} catch {error-handling} finally {finishing-moves}`

Comment: so You have catch block Inside try block. You need catch block outside, right after try block. 
It's easier to see if You use Visual Studio Code, really helps :)
Also  - there's great importexcel module on Github  - not sure if it supports importing password protected files, but it's worth checking up probably.

Comment: Thanks guys, for the quick responses. @LievenKeersmaekers, I tried adding a } as you suggested after the '} #end foreach worksheet', but I'm still getting an error in the same place. Dumb question, but does the '}' placement matter (on the same line, or new line?)?

Comment: @tomek, do you have the link to the importexcel module on GitHub?

Comment: @viRg the placement of the `}` matters only if you accidentally write it in the same line after the `#end foreach worksheet` and the new `}` is interpreted as a comment

Comment: @viRg so You have Two options: 
1)https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel
2)You can download directly from powershell Gallery, like this 
Install-Module -Name ImportExcel

Answer (score 2):

Try using **catch [System.Exception]**

If you get the error:

> The Catch block is missing its statement block

This is a compile time error.
If you have something like this:

```
try 
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
        write $_ 
        return 'test'
    }
```

Try enclosing the exception in brackets, not parenthesis:

```
try 
    {
        ...
    }
    catch [System.Exception]
    {
        write $_ 
        return 'test'
    }
```

Comment: It is important to leave a whitespace between `catch ` and the exception. In this case, `[System.Exception]`. Such a mistake led to a very misleading error, an it took me a while to figure out what I had done wrong

Answer (score 1):

Your `catch` statement is in the wrong place. Currently it is placed after the `foreach` block, but it has to be placed after the `try` block.

```
        } #end foreach worksheet
    } #end try, SHOULD END TRY BEFORE STARTING CATCH
    catch {
        Out-File -FilePath $LogCSV -InputObject "$($File.FullName);File is password protected - skipped;" -Append
    } #end catch
} #end for each file
```